# Rails slim form_for tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

I am having trouble getting a form to work after switching from regular ERB to slim files. Here is the form I am trying to have slim render:

```
= form_for @student, :url => students_path(@student), method: :post do |f|
    = f.hidden_field :student_id, :value => current_user.id
    = f.hidden_field :course_id, :value => group.id
    = submit_tag "Join this Class!", :class => "btn btn-primary pull-right join-button"
```

Here was the working code in regular ERB file

```
<%= form_for @student, :url => students_path(@student), method: :post do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :student_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :course_id, :value => group.id %>
    <%= submit_tag "+ Join", :class => "btn btn-primary pull-right join-button" %>
<% end %>
```

This is the error I am currently getting:

```
undefined local variable or method `f'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most problem with slim it is indents try this(two space after `form_for`):

```
= form_for @student, :url => students_path(@student), method: :post do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :student_id, :value => current_user.id
  = f.hidden_field :course_id, :value => group.id
  = submit_tag "Join this Class!", :class => "btn btn-primary pull-right join-button"
```

Comment: nice! Thank you for your help. It was an indentation issue. The form is already indented on the page, and the hidden fields are indented from the form, but then there are spaces before the tabs. I dont know if that makes sense, but yes you are correct, it was an indentation issue! Thank You

Comment: yep this is very furry bug. `tab != two space`